# mysql use parameters to alter partition

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I wrote a query that should update the last partition in my db

```
set @last_partition = (
  select PARTITION_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS
  where TABLE_NAME='my_table'
  and PARTITION_DESCRIPTION ='MAXVALUE')

set @last_partition_range := SUBSTR(@last_partition,2) 
set @next_partition := concat('p', YEARWEEK(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@last_partition_range,' Sunday'), '%X%V %W') + INTERVAL 1 WEEK));


ALTER TABLE `my-db`.my_table
REORGANIZE PARTITION @last_partition INTO (
    PARTITION @last_partition VALUES LESS THAN (@last_partition_range),
    PARTITION @next_partition VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

but I get the following error:

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@last_partition INTO (

    PARTITION @last_partition VALUES LESS THAN (@last_pa' at line 2
```

when I put the values without the variable the alter query runs succefully:

```
select @last_partition, @last_partition_range, @next_partition
-- p202152  202152  p202201

ALTER TABLE `my-db`.my_table
REORGANIZE PARTITION p202152 INTO (

    PARTITION p202152 VALUES LESS THAN (202152),
    PARTITION p202201 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @c = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `my-db`.my_table ',
'REORGANIZE PARTITION ',@last_partition, ' INTO ( ',
  'PARTITION ',@last_partition, ' VALUES LESS THAN (', @last_partition_range, '), ',
  'PARTITION ',@next_partition, ' VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ',
')');


PREPARE stmt from @c;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```